# WPF Context Menu is not in Windows 10 Style

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I'm developing a simple WPF application. I don't use any custom styling. So it looks native on Windows 7 and 10. But today I have noticed that the context menu looks odd on Windows 10:

[image: Screenshot]

In other applications like 7-Zip, context menus look native:

[image: Z-Zip]

How can I apply the flat Window 10 style to my context menus without breaking the native look on Windows 7?

**Clarification:** My context menu has a 3D split line on the left hand and a border around the selction. In 7-Zip, Explorer and other applications, there are neither a 3D split line nor a border around selctions. I'm used that WPF applications looks unlike Java Swing as a nativ Windows application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But today I have noticed that the context menu looks odd on Windows 10:

Odd or not, this is actually how the default WPF ContextMenu looks like on Windows 10.

> How can I apply the flat Window 10 style to my context menus without breaking the native look on Windows 7?

You need to define this "flat Window 10 style" yourself. There is an example of how to create a custom ContextMenu style available on MSDN that should get you started: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms744758%28v=vs.110%29.aspx. There is no quick fix.

Answer (score 0):

You're getting hung up on the shortcut keys (>, Enter, Ctrl + PgDn, etc).  Your application isn't assigning any, while 7-zip *is* assigning them.  Or maybe, the outlining.  Don't get thrown off.  Things are working exactly as they should.

But let's not overlook the fact that if 7-zip is not written in WPF, you can't expect the same results.

Comment: I think he meant the difference in highlighting of menu items

Comment: That's possible.  However, we can't assume the mechanism 7-zip is using to render them is the exact same as the OP's code.  If 7-zip is not written in WPF, this would be the most obvious difference -- the underlying code differs.

Comment: @codenoir: I suppose that should be the answer then - a more general explanation how and why selection in WPF works (and thus, necessarily, looks) somewhat differently from selection in any native Windows GUI toolkit.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper Duly noted.

Comment: @codenoir: Sorry, I think the current explanation is still a bit too thin to be useful. I had a link about the selection somewhere, might go looking for it later. The issue is that the *usual* case is that for any two commonly used GUI toolkits in Windows, you *could* usually expect the same results, because those GUI toolkits were mostly just wrappers for Windows's native GUI API. It's really especially WPF that is an exception in this respect as it draws everything itself.