# WPF context menu spacing differs on different windows versions

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

we are facing an issue where we see that out context menu spacing, especially around the separators is different between Windows 10 and Windows 7.

[image: context menu on windows 7]
[image: context menu on windows 10]
Sorry for the scaling, but it is obvious that on windows /top) the spacing around the separators is bigger than in Windows 10.

Strange thing is that we looked at the vosual tree, and the separators in windows 10 have a different template than on windows 7.
In windows 10 it contains a boarder object,
in wndows 7 a grid with 2 rectangles.

How can we make sure the separators look the same?
Why is this actually happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why is this actually happening?

Because the default styles for the built-in controls look different on different versions and themes on Windows.

> How can we make sure the separators look the same?

If you want to apply the look of a specific Windows 7 theme to an application running on Windows 10, you could add a theme resource dictionary to your `App.xaml` file:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="/PresentationFramework.Aero, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, ProcessorArchitecture=MSIL;component/themes/aero.normalcolor.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

You need to reference the corresponding assembly, `PresentationFramework.Aero.dll` in this case.

Comment: What if I want the windows 10 style? In windows 7

Comment: On Windows 7? Then you will need to define a Window 10 style yourself. You may start from the default one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41003094/wpf-context-menu-is-not-in-windows-10-style/41004129#41004129.

Comment: strange is how this occurred seemingly out of nowhere. This can't be right, it looks like the standard style (Aero) is somehow broken.